# How can you format y-axis differently in each subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, lambda, seaborn

I have the following piece of code that draws some subplots:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0, 1], [1, 0]], columns=['prc_col', 'money_col'])
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)
fig.tight_layout(pad=5.0)
formatting_dict = {'prc_col': lambda num: f'{round(num)}%', 'money_col': lambda num: f'${round(num)}'}
for idx, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    ax = axs[idx]
    g = sns.boxplot(data=df, y=col, showfliers=False, ax=ax)
    g.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: formatting_dict[col](x)))
plt.show()
```

and I would like to see y-axis for boxplot corresponding to prc_column to be formatted as percentages and y-axis for money_col to be formatted as money. However, both plots get formatted as money, as seen in the picture below.

[image: Output I get]

Comment: `formatting_dict = {'prc_col': lambda num, pos: f'{round(num)}%', 'money_col': lambda num, pos: f'${round(num)}'}` together with `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatting_dict[col])` seems to work well. But I'm without clue what the real problem with the original code could be.

Comment: When I try `formatting_dict_with_pos = {'prc_col': lambda num, pos: formatting_dict['prc_col'](num), 'money_col': lambda num, pos: formatting_dict['money_col'](num)}` with the original dict, things work as hoped for. But writing any kind of loop, e.g.  `formatting_dict_with_pos = {key: lambda num, pos: formatting_dict[key](num) for key in formatting_dict.keys()}` makes the last entry overwrite the previous one.  It isn't related to matplotlib, but something Python-specific about lambda functions in loops.